# how to get lexicographic order of a string having an alphabet

Tags: java, dictionary, encoding, lexicographic

i have an alphabet composed of 4 letters [a, c, g, t].

i have an incremental dictionary of these letters:

```
[a, c, g, t, aa, ac, ag, at, aaa, aac, aag, aat, aca, acc, acg, act, aga, agc, agg, agt, ata, atc, atg, att, aaaa ...]
```

i want to assign to each string of the dictionary an encoding which is different from all other encodings.

for example:

```
a=1
c=2
g=3
t=4
aa=5
ac=6
ag=7
at=8
aaa=9
aac=10
ecc...
```

how i can do this?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Here, isn't the encoded value equal to its index?

Comment: @O.KOO i use java

Comment: @it is possible, but i don't know how to do that

Comment: @AndreaMantovani it will be helpful if you post some code that you have tried.

Comment: Is the encoding just sequential positive integers starting from 1? or you have specific values for each string in your dictionary?

Comment: @ O.KOO i just want a UNIQUE encoding for each string in my dictionary. The positive integers explanation is only an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Hashmap`

here is the code:

```
List<String> test= Arrays.asList("a", "c", "g","t", "aa","ac","ag","at","aaa","aac","aag","aat","aca","acc","aaaa");
HashMap<String, Integer> encodeValue = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
int i = 1;
for(String value : test){
    if(!encodeValue.containsKey(value)){
        encodeValue.put(value, new Integer(i));
        i++;
        }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(encodeValue));
```

The output

```
[{
g=3,
aac=10, 
aaa=9, 
c=2, 
aag=11,
a=1, 
at=8, 
acc=14,
t=4, 
aaaa=15,
aat=12, 
ac=6, 
aa=5, 
ag=7, 
aca=13
}]
```

Its not in order but all string has a unique encode value to it.

Hope this helps and welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find this answer or any other answer solves your problem please mark it as the solution to help the community and others who has same question as you did.